# Kendo dropdown search design issue

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

[Kendo Dropdown search design Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeGGz.png)
search option is coming out of kendo dropdown only in internet explorer.

it is working fine in chrome, is there anyway to adjust search textbox in kendo dropdown to left.

Comment: Can you please share fiddler or something ?

Comment: thanks  Parthiv Pandya, i got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add IE Edge compatibility tag

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
and,add following style

     .k-list-filter > .k-icon {
                    position:absolute;
                    right:5px;(as per your requirement)
                    top:auto;
                }
```